# Move File only if the file does not contain only a zero

Tags: powershell

I have the below powershell command which, if the file only contains a zero and no spaces after, works ok.

However, my file has multiple spaces after the `0`, followed by a newline.

How can I only move the file if the only character in the file is a `0`, no matter on whether there are additional spaces and lines?

```
$file = Get-Content "Test\A28AP.txt" -raw
if ($file -notmatch '^0$') {
   Move-Item "D:\Test\A28AP.txt" -Destination "D:\Test\History"
}
```

Comment: `\s*` matches any arbitrary amount of whitespace, including nothing. But arguably `.Trim() -eq "0"` is cleaner than regexing.

Comment: I have tried

if ($file.Trim -eq '0') {
   Move-Item "Test\A28AP.txt" -Destination "Test\History"
}

Answer (score 1):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) suggests, using `.Trim()` on the file's content before comparing to string `'0'` is the simplest solution in your case:

```
$filePath = 'Test\A28AP.txt'
if ('0' -ne (Get-Content $filePath -Raw).Trim()) {
   Move-Item $filePath -Destination D:\Test\History -WhatIf
}
```

`.Trim()` ([`System.String.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Trim)) removes all leading and trailing whitespace, and is complemented by `.TrimStart()` and `.TrimEnd()` variants. All these methods optionally allow you to control the set of characters to be trimmed.

---

To look on the *first line* only, irrespective of whether there are additional, non-empty ones, replace `-Raw` with `-First 1`

---

For the sake of completeness, here's the equivalent (first-line-only) regex solution - even though it is overkill in your case:

```
$filePath = 'Test\A28AP.txt'
if ((Get-Content $filePath -First 1) -notmatch '^0 *') {
   Move-Item $filePath -Destination D:\Test\History -WhatIf
}
```

`' *'` matches zero or more spaces after the `0` at the start of the string (`^`).

---

With a given *multi-line* input string (which is what `-Raw` returns for a multi-line file), limiting matching to the first line requires more effort:

- By default, `^` and `$` in .NET regexes match only the very beginning and end of the *entire input*; inline option `(?m)` can be used to make them match on *each line*, in which case `\A` and `\Z` / `\z` must be used to match the very beginning and end of the string - see the [.NET regex quick reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Therefore, use regex `'(?m)\A0 *$'` to look for a `0` with optional trailing spaces only on the first line of the multi-line string:

```
$filePath = 'Test\A28AP.txt'
if ((Get-Content $filePath -Raw) -notmatch '(?m)\A0 *$') {
   Move-Item $filePath -Destination D:\Test\History -WhatIf
}
```